# Using AutoMapper to map unknown types

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, automapper

I'm using `AutoMapper` to copy the properties of one object to another: This is my code:

```
// Get type and create first object
Type itemType = Type.GetType(itemTypeName);
var item = Activator.CreateInstance(itemType);

// Set item properties
.. Code removed for clarity ..

// Get item from Entity Framework DbContext
var set = dataContext.Set(itemType);
var itemInDatabase = set.Find(id);
if (itemInDatabase == null)
{
    itemInDatabase = Activator.CreateInstance(itemType);
    set.Add(itemInDatabase);
}

// Copy item to itemInDatabase
Mapper.CreateMap(itemType, itemType);
Mapper.Map(item, itemInDatabase);

// Save changes
dataContext.SaveChanges();
```

The problem is that `Mapper.Map()` throws an `AutoMapperMappingException`:

```
Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping.

Mapping types:
Object -> MachineDataModel
System.Object -> MyProject.DataModels.MachineDataModel

Destination path:
MachineDataModel

Source value:
MyProject.DataModels.MachineDataModel
```

I don't really understand what the problem is, and what can I do to fix it?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need to use the non-generic overload of `Map`:

```
Mapper.Map(item, itemInDatabase, item.GetType(), itemInDatabase.GetType());
```

The reason is that the generic version you are currently using doesn't use the runtime type of the instances you pass. Rather it uses the compile time type - and the compile time type of `item` is `object` because that's the return value of `Activator.CreateInstance`.

Comment: Haha, I was gonna tell you to switch the order of the parameters, but you were too fast. But it works like a charm! I'll accept your answer as soon as I can.

Comment: @Joel: Yeah, I first wrote down the relevant parts and then looked up the correct ordering :)